# iOS create UITabBar who's items can user change dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I would like to create `UITabBar` with three items.

Each item would lead to different `UIViewController`.

The `UITabBar` has to bee editable, so that the user can change items while using the app.

Example:

In `UITabBar` I have by default itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree.

When user taps itemThree he is shown a selection view, where he can select itemFour, itemFive, itemSix, ... to replace one of the items in `UITabBar`.

So if he decides to replace itemSix with itemTwo, he has to tap itemTwo and then in selection view itemSix and the items have to replace.

So now when the user taps itemSix in the `UITabBar` the app has to take him to the `UIViewController` which is connected with itemSix.

My idea is to create `UIViewController` with `UIView` as the custom `UITabBar` and the `ContainerView` which would serve as a placeholder for different `UIViewControllers`.

Please can you comment my idea and tell me about your suggestion how should I implement this sort of functionality.

Comment: If you have more than five tabs, `UITabBar` generates a “More” item that allows you to do exactly this. The only difference is that four tabs are always displayed, not 3.

Comment: I can't use "More". I have to have three items all the time and a special selection view to handle selection.

Comment: You can customise `Tab Bar` with subclass of  `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

The `-beginCustomizingItems:` and `-endCustomizingAnimated:` methods on `UITabBar` <sup>[(docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW16)</sup> can allow something like this.

> **`- (void)beginCustomizingItems:(NSArray<UITabBarItem *> *)items`**
>
> The `items` parameter should contain all items that can be added to the tab bar. **Visible items not in `items` are fixed in place—they can not be removed or replaced by the user**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I can't use that either. I have to use my custom presentation view which is essentially `UICollectionView` because if the user want's he can also rearrange the items in the `UICollectionView`. So no iOS native views come in play.

Comment: Is the custom `UIView` that plays the role as a `UITabBar` only solution? What is your opinion on that?